# Redirect https ip to domain in htaccess in shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla3.0, http-redirect, no-www

Google has indexed my website IP address with ssl and because I use ssl on my website I get error "error Your connection is not private".
I know there are a lot of question on stackoverflow  like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348545/htaccess-redirect-from-ip-adress-to-actual-domain).

Edited: Fist of all I thought this code doesn't work but then I understood that below code doesn't cause redirect https://ip to main domain.
It works fine with http and redirect all subfolders, too. I use share hosting.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can this problem is related to the place I put this code in htaccess file? I use joomla CMS on my website.
I also redirect http and www to https and non www with below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mail.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Can anyone help me? All the links I found are about dedicated server.

Edited: I have add my htaccess file here:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2017 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by your 
# server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the 
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If 
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to 
# set it here.
##

## No directory listings
<IfModule autoindex>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^45\.138\.133\.59$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mail.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$


## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed 
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

 RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  FileETag MTime Size
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month "
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

## BEGIN EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType application/font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff2
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff2
# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
## END EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Your rule looks correct. Just place it below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: I believe your htaccess rules `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111$` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]` should be first 2 Rules of your `.htaccess` file under `RewriteEngine ON`, could you please try it once and let me know how it goes then?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please your rules in your first 2 lines(after `RewriteEngine ON` line). Please try following rules and make sure you clear your cache before testing URLs. NOTE: I have not changed any of your rules, I have only changed the order of Rules here.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mail.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments but unfortunately the problem is not solved for https by changing the order of the rules. I cleared the cache and even wait for a day to become sure that it works or not. By the way my website is made by joomla, do you think a component or plugin can cause this problem? I have attached the full htaccess file to my question . Right now https://111.111.111.111/something is not redirected to https://example.com/something. But it works fine for http.

Comment: hello, joomla was not initially tagged  in question I believe, I am sorry but I have not worked on it else would have tried something here. May be @anubhava sir could help here if he could.

Comment: Dear @RavinderSingh13, I think it is some thing wrong with my rules and it's not related to joomla. Because as I told, right now http://myip/something with http is redirected correctly to https://example.com/something with https . The problem is with https://myip with https because right now there is no rule for that. Am I right?

Comment: @Sarah, condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111$` IMHO should work, I need to check on what could be the issue here. May be other GURUs could also jump to this issue. Will post here if I get some points here, thank you.